# Pop-Up Div on Top?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, popup

Hello, I have two pop-up divs that pop-up when clicking on the main navigation. Currently, the second div always stays on top so you have to close it to get to the first div. Here's a link my website so you can see what I'm talking about: http://nshek.com/

When you click mixed media and then photography, there's no problem. However, I'd like to make it so when you click mixed media when the photo pop-up open, it shows on top.

Any help would be much appreciated. Here's the code for my navigation & pop-ups.

```
<ul id="topnav">
<li><a href = "javascript:void(0)" onclick = "document.getElementById('print').style.display='block';document.getElementById('fade').style.display='block'">mixed media/prints</a></li>
    <div id="print" class="white_content">
    <div id="link">
    <b>prints</b>
    <br />-<a href="/photobased.php">photo-based</a>
    <br />-<a href="/silkscreen.php">silkscreen</a>
    <br />-<a href="/relief.php">relief/monoprint</a>
    <br />-<a href="/litho.php">lithography</a>


    <br><b>other mediums</b>
    <br />-<a href="">mixed media</a>
    <br />-<a href="">paintings</a>
    </div>
    <br><br>
    <div id="close"><a href = "javascript:void(0)" onclick = "document.getElementById('print').style.display='none';document.getElementById('fade').style.display='none'">Close</a></div>
    </div>

<li><a href = "javascript:void(0)" onclick = "document.getElementById('light').style.display='block';document.getElementById('fade').style.display='block'">photography</a></li>
    <div id="light" class="white_content">
    <b>digital photography</b>
    <br /><div id="link">
    -<a href="">list series</a>
    <br />-<a href="/">view all</a>
    </div>
    <br><b>film photography</b>
    <br /><div id="link">
    -<a href="/cafilm.php">california, usa</a>
    <br />-<a href="/hkfilm.php">hong kong</a>
    <br />-<a href="/miscfilm.php">miscellaneous</a>
    </div>
    <br><br>
    <div id="close"><a href = "javascript:void(0)" onclick = "document.getElementById('light').style.display='none';document.getElementById('fade').style.display='none'">Close</a></div>
    </div>

<li><a href="/digitalworks.php">digital works</a></li>
<li><a href="/CV.php">CV/resumé</a></li>
<li><a href="/contact.php">contact</a></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add the script you have for hiding your divs to your script for revealing a div when the menu items are clicked on so that when you click a menu item your code first hides all divs that can toggle back and forth then reveals only the one that corresponds to the menu item you just clicked.

Also, you have assigned the id "close" to two different divs. Id's should be unique - used only once.  Make "close" a class not and ID to avoid this.

Answer (score 0):

In your case you are just not hiding next popup, and it could have higher z-index than your first one, so you just need to hide it first, then next div popups normally.
Solution via jQuery:

```
$('#showFirst').bind('click', function(){
    $('#1').show();
    $('#2').hide();
})
```

Here is fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/Goodluck/uxv73/